Django 'When' object is not iterable
I'm using django-filter to show work-hour of employs.
models.py:
    ...
    class Attendance(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Attendances")
        day = models.DateField()
        start_time = models.TimeField()
        end_time = models.TimeField()
        is_confirmed = models.BooleanField()
        task = models.ForeignKey(Tasks, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        
     class Task(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Tasks")
        assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       
    ...

filter.py:
class WorkhourFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False),field_name="user")
    project = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Project.objects.all(), field_name="task__project")
    year = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=tuple((x, x) for x in settings.YEARS_LIST),method='year_search')
    month = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=tuple((i, x) for i, x in enumerate(settings.MONTH_LIST)),method='month_search' )
    
    class Meta:
    model = Attendance
    fields = ['user']
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(WorkhourFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         start_date = ...
         end_date = ...
         self.queryset = self.Meta.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, 
         day__gte=start_date, day__lte=end_date).values('task__project__title', 
         'task__project').annotate(
          raw_work_hour=Sum(F('end_time') - F('start_time'), ),
          confirmed_work_hour=Sum(Case(When(is_verified=1, 
          then=F('end_time') - 
          F('start_time'))))).order_by('task__project')

I get 'When' object is not iterable error.
confirmed_work_hour has problem but the raw_work_hour alone is not a problem.
This query is working well in get_queryset() of corresponding View but when I trying to apply filters it'll break.
trace :
Django Version: 4.2.5
Python Version: 3.9.13
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_extensions',
 'crispy_forms',
 'crispy_bootstrap5',
 'django_tables2',
 'django_htmx',
 'django_filters',
 'ckeditor',
 'ckeditor_uploader',
 'guardian',
 'django_cascading_dropdown_widget',
 'dashboard.apps.DashboardsConfig',
 'auth.apps.AuthConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django_htmx.middleware.HtmxMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 73, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_access.py", line 438, in dispatch
    return super(StaffuserRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\braces\views\_access.py", line 375, in dispatch
    return super(GroupRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 143, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django_filters\views.py", line 74, in get
    self.filterset = self.get_filterset(filterset_class)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\django_filters\views.py", line 38, in get_filterset
    return filterset_class(**kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\dashboard\filters\workhour_project.py", line 71, in __init__
    confirmed_work_hour=Sum(Case(When(is_verified=1, then=F('end_time') - F('start_time')))),
  File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 160, in __init__
    [setattr(token, 'parent', self) for token in self.tokens]

Exception Type: TypeError at /report/workhour/by_project
Exception Value: 'When' object is not iterable


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.

Can you also explain what you are exactly filtering? A project? task, attendance?

It seems like you want to filter the Project instead, but somehow picked Attendance as model for the filter?

I have multiple filters(edited code) . but problem is on initial load and I can't test other filters yet

But what are you planning to filter? Projects or Attendance objects, what should be displayed as result? Currently it looks like the queryset is an odd way to filter Projects.

In fact, Attendance objects are filtered. Each Attendance record includes the time of entry and exit. Since each Attendance record is related to a task, the said task is a child of a project. So Attendance records are grouped and filtered based on projects. In the meantime, there are some other filters.

The report will actually show the hours spent on each project. Raw hours and confirmed hours. Because some hours spent may not be approved by the admin.

Thanks to all friends who took the time to solve my problem.
Looking again at the error trace in the last lines, I noticed a wrong import. Of course, last comment of @willeM_VanOnsem forced me to look at imports again and I am grateful to him.
The Case command was mistakenly imported from sqlparse.sql when it should have been imported from django.db.models.
By applying the above change, the code worked smoothly.
The desired line in the trace that pointed to the sqlparse package:
File "D:\Python\DjangoTest\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 160, in __init__
    [setattr(token, 'parent', self) for token in self.tokens]


problem not in When, problem is - Case(When are wrapped in Count.
in your case solution is to split Case(When and Count in two annottate( declaration:
manager = self.Meta.model.objects
queryset = manager.filter(user=self.request.user, day__gte=start_date, day__lte=end_date)
queryset = queryset.values('task__project__title', 'task__project').order_by('task__project')
queryset = queryset.annotate(raw_work_hour=Sum(F('end_time') - F('start_time'), ), work_hour=Case(When(is_verified=1, then=F('end_time') - F('start_time')), default=0))

But i don't understand, what you want to Sum.
queryset = queryset.annotate(confirmed_work_hour = Sum('work_hour'))  # Probably it is not needed.


Hmmm, thanks, but I don't quite understand what you mean by two annotate? A query including two annotates or two queries? I have no experience in implementing this.

probably you dont need to use sum. Please check. Sum are designed for aggregation and not for annotation.

I think there's a problem with "default". I got __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default' .

@LittleElite: there is a problem with the parenthesis, the default=... belongs to the Case, not the When.

already  it's inside Case. but still has the error

Oops! Importing from the wrong package!
